# How to show data with group by and where in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, where-clause

I use this case to show data follow `where` and `group by` . Sample in case `18/12/2017`.

```
SELECT 
    PROID,
    MAX(COUNT_NUMBER) AS COUNT_NUMBER_OLD,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 101) AS PreDate
FROM 
    TABLE_A
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATETIME_INPUT, 108) BETWEEN '18' AND '23'
    AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 103) = '18/12/2017'
GROUP BY 
    PROID, CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 101);
```

The result is:

```
PROID     COUNT_NUMBER_OLD      PreDate
-------------------------------------------
01        1063                  12/18/2017
02        365                   12/18/2017
03        845                   12/18/2017
```

It's working normal, but I want to show data if not have data in where condition. For example: `CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 103)  = '17/12/2017'`:

```
PROID     COUNT_NUMBER_OLD      PreDate
------------------------------------------
01        0                     12/17/2017
02        0                     12/17/2017
03        0                     12/17/2017
```

I try with

```
(CASE 
    WHEN COUNT_NUMBER IS NULL 
       THEN 0 
       ELSE MAX(COUNT_NUMBER) 
 END) AS COUNT_NUMBER_OLD
```

but I get this error:

> Column 'TABLE_A.COUNT_NUMBER' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What do you mean by *i want to show data if not have data in where condition*?

Comment: Exactly, i want show data as ```0``` if where condition not have data

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery and get the max count_number for each group and then do a ISNULL operation.

```
SELECT X.PROID,
       ISNULL(X.COUNT_NUMBER,0) AS COUNT_NUMBER_OLD,
       X.PreDate
FROM
(SELECT PROID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROID,CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 101) ORDER BY COUNT_NUMBER DESC) AS RN,
       CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 101) AS PreDate,
       COUNT_NUMBER
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATETIME_INPUT, 108) BETWEEN '18' AND '23'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 103) = '18/12/2017' ) X
WHERE X.RN=1
```

Comment: It's not working, i want to show as ```PROID     COUNT_NUMBER_OLD      PreDate
------------------------------------------
01        0                     12/17/2017
02        0                     12/17/2017
03        0                     12/17/2017```

Comment: @BrianCrist What's the output of my query. Since you didn't add sample data, I can't check the output.

Comment: the result of you not show any row .I want to show 0 when data not have.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that your column might have NULL values.

By default the functions MAX and MIN do not count NULL in their evaluation of your data.  If the COUNT_NUMBER column contains NULL values, MAX and MIN will both ignore that value.

Try this solution.

```
SELECT PROID,
       MAX(COALESCE(COUNT_NUMBER,0)) AS COUNT_NUMBER_OLD,
       CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 101) AS PreDate
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATETIME_INPUT, 108) BETWEEN '18' AND '23'
AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 103) = '17/12/2017'
GROUP BY PROID,
         CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATETIME_INPUT, 101);
```

Comment: It's not working, not show any row .I want to show ```PROID     COUNT_NUMBER_OLD      PreDate
------------------------------------------
01        0                     12/17/2017
02        0                     12/17/2017
03        0                     12/17/2017```

Comment: Does the column count_number contain null values?  can you provide an email of the underlying table?